# Rails API how do I send the active record validation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have model `User` with `validates_uniqueness_of :email`. In the front end (react), if I try to register with an address that's already taken, rails returns a 422 error. How can I instead send the error message to the front end?

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.create!(
      email: params['user']['email'],
      name: params['user']['name'],
      password: params['user']['password'],
      password_confirmation: params['user']['password_confirmation']
    )
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      render json: {
        status: :created,
        user: user
      }
    else
      render json: { status: 500 }
    end
  end
end
```

React (axios):

```
.catch(error => {
        console.log("registration error", error);
      });
```

Console shows the error as `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`
[image]

trying to log error.response doesn't show the activerecord error either
[image]

Whereas in rails console I can see the error message
[image]

Solved, the problem was using `create!`
Managed to display the error nicely with

`render json: { errors: user.errors.full_messages }, status: 500`
`error.response.data.errors.join("; ")`

Comment: 422 - means this is problem on RoR api

Comment: This worked for me: error.response.data.errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `create!`, which means if the record is invalid, it raises an exception, so the code that's after that's not going to be executed.

You can try first building your User, and then try to save it, if it couldn't, then you're able to render the errors on that object that prevent to persist it into the database:

```
user = User.new(
  email: params['user']['email'],
  name: params['user']['name'],
  password: params['user']['password'],
  password_confirmation: params['user']['password_confirmation']
)
if user.save
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  render json: {
    status: :created,
    user: user
  }
else
  render json: { status: 500, errors: user.errors }
end
```

Comment: thanks, should the `status: 500` be inside or outside the curly braces?

Comment: Currently with `JSON.stringify(error.response.data.errors)` I get `{"password_confirmation":["doesn't match Password"],"email":["has already been taken"]}`, is there any nice way to display the errors such as it did in the rails console?

Comment: That's a good question, but depends totally in your case. If you're expecting to receive an HTTP status in your response, it can go outside the braces, if you're just working with that in the front end it can go within the JSON response.

Comment: Maybe using `full_errors` (`user.errors.full_messages`)?  Take a look to the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages), it has examples of what your case might need.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.new(
      email: params['user']['email'],
      name: params['user']['name'],
      password: params['user']['password'],
      password_confirmation: params['user']['password_confirmation']
    )
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      render json: {
        status: :created,
        user: user
      }
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 500
    end
  end
end
```

After that your validations will be available here:

```
.catch(error => {
        console.log("registration error", error.response.data.errors);
      });
```

So you will receive array of validation errors

Comment: thanks, should the `status: 500` be inside or outside the curly braces?

Comment: Currently with `JSON.stringify(error.response.data.errors)` I get `{"password_confirmation":["doesn't match Password"],"email":["has already been taken"]}`, is there any nice way to display the errors such as it did in the rails console?